# Diagnostics and troubleshooting for products -Oracle R12

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

How can the diagnostics and troubleshooting for products be done in Oracle iStore release 12 ?? Is there any query to check that??I mean the query for Catalog, Pricing Errors.

Comment: This is a really specialist area.  You're more likely to get a knowledgeable answer if you post your question on the dedicated Oracle EBS forum: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of errors you would like to monitor. based on your error definition you could have a look at tables like `MTL_ITEM_CATALOG_GROUPS`, for pricing related info look into tables like `ASO_PRICE_ADJUSTMENTS`, `ASO_PRICE_ADJ_RELATIONSHIPS`, `ASO_PRICE_ATTRIBUTES` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for `catalog errors`. I think I need to check,`IBE: Use Web Placements,MO: Operating Unit,IBE: Item Validation Organization` etc. For that how can I write PL/SQL queries? Or do we need to query it using `like'%Profile_Option_name%'` like operator?? Tables:`fnd_profile_options_vl ,fnd_profile_option_values` Thanks